# How to use xml query to get data from following websites

Tags: excel, xml, vba, web-scraping

Hi I want to get patent number and abstract data from following two websites:

I know how to scrape data from these website using HTML query, I was wondering if there is a way to get data using XML query.

```vb
Sub google()

 Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim pageText, pageclaim As String
    Dim HTMLTable, HTMLp As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables, HTMLps As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer
    Dim pointer  As Integer
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate ""
    
    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

End sub
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't know if you automatically got a hint after I edited my answer. I have added a working version for the Google Link to my answer

Comment: thanks, for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

I thought again and remembered that you can hand over the UserAgent as well. So you can get the HTML source code of the page for the Google link:

```
Sub google()
  Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  Dim htmlDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
  Dim url As String
  
  url = "https://patents.google.com/patent/US8805587B1/en?oq=US8805587B1"
  
  http.Open "GET", url, False
  http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
  http.Send
  htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
  
  Close
  Open "D:\httpRequest.txt" For Output As #1
  Print #1, htmlDoc.body.outerHTML
  Close
  'Debug.Print htmlDoc.body.outerHTML
End Sub
```

### First posting (The part for the second link is still valid)

~~Bad news. The first page doesn't work with XML requests:~~

```
Sub google()
  Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  Dim htmlDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
  Dim url As String
  
  url = "https://patents.google.com/patent/US8805587B1/en?oq=US8805587B1"
  
  http.Open "GET", url, False
  http.Send
  htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
  
  Debug.Print htmlDoc.body.outerHTML
End Sub
```

This is the result:

```html
<BODY>
  <DIV style="MAX-WIDTH: 590px; MARGIN: 64px auto 0px">
    <H2>Your Browser Isn't Supported By Google Patents</H2>
    <P>It looks like you're using an old browser which isn't supported by Google Patents. To use Google Patents, you'll need an up-to-date browser.
      <A href="https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6261372">Learn more</A>.
    </P>
  </DIV>
</BODY>
```

The second page doesn't work with XML requests, because it's a dynamic content page. XML requests can only work with static HTML which means the first delivered HTML from an URL call.